# How to get a column value from each row from dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

all.

I'd like to get 'ID' column value and print them for each row. Currently my code is returning row index + 'ID' column value.

Here's an output:

> ID= 0    109 Name: id, dtype: int64 coordinate: [   75.
>   20.19276294  2903.        ] label: 1

Here's my code:

```
for i in range(len(X)):
   print ("ID=", df['ID'].loc[[i]], "coordinate:" , X[i], "label:", labels[i])
```

If I print 'ID' column, stored values look like this:

```
print(df['ID'])

0      109
1      110
2      111
```

I only want 'ID' values to be printed out, here's what I expect.

> ID: 109  coordinate: [   75.     20.19276294  2903.        ] label: 1

Comment: .values on the column should do the job

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the array from the loc function:

```
for i in range(len(X)):
    print ("ID=", df['ID'].loc[i], "coordinate:" , X[i], "label:", labels[i])
```

And you should consider using `iloc` instead of `loc` since `loc` is label based and `iloc` is integer based (row number).